# Is it possible to store a List<T> in SSIS as variable

Tags: c#, variables, ssis

I have been trying to store a list of data in one of my scripts to be used in another script later in my data flow. I have tried assigning my list as an object variable but can't seem to get it to work, is this possible?

Comment: Good question. I have used `List<T>` within a Script Task, but have not tried to put it in a variable.

Comment: @MikeHenderson answer is below, just need to typecast the object in the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will simply have to cast it from an Object type back to the appropriate List type. I did a similar thing in when I was doing some [performance testing on filter lists](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/filter-list-in-ssis.html)